# Swift 1.2 NSTextStorage removeAttribute with Range<String.Index>

Tags: ios, swift, textkit

I have a subclass of `NSTextStorage` and I'm trying to remove the foreground color of a paragraph the following way:

```
var paragraphRange = self.string.paragraphRangeForRange(
        advance(self.string.startIndex, theRange.location)..advance(self.string.startIndex, theRange.location + theRange.length))

self.removeAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, range: paragraphRange)
```

However, I get the following error `Cannot invoke 'removeAttribute' with an argument list of type '(String, range: (Range<String.Index>))'`

Help Please. I think *TextKit* on Swift is a mess. Some methods receive/return `NSRange` but String works with `Range<String.Index>` making it a hell to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `NSString` returned by `self.string`
is automatically bridged to a Swift `String`. A possible solution is
to convert it back to `NSString` explicitly:

```
func removeColorForRange(theRange : NSRange) {
    let paragraphRange = (self.string as NSString).paragraphRangeForRange(theRange)
    self.removeAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, range: paragraphRange)
}
```

Note also that the range operator `..` has been replaced by `..<`
in newer Swift versions (to avoid confusion with `...` and to 
emphasize that the upper bound is not included).